# How to generate 5 MHz clock with 50% duty cycle?

Tags: oscillator, frequency, clock

How to generate a 5 MHz clock with 50 percent duty cycle? I have an application that requires a continuous clock signal to operate. 555 timer is an easy option but it generates only up to 1 MHz frequency. I know that there are various crystal oscillators available but not sure how to connect.

The application is for a printer. The data is loaded into the printer ICs clock signal is high and with a constant frequency of 5MHz.

I need to design a clock generator to load this data into the ICs. The interface connector has 2 input pins, one for data and the other is for clock signal.

[image]

Comment: I think 50% duty cycle for a 555 might be problematic so, what are your real requirements?

Comment: Just buy a crystal oscillator module that outputs a square wave

Comment: Iomesh - Hi, you said: "*there are various crystal oscillators available but not sure how to connect.*" You're not sure how to connect the oscillator **to what**? You haven't told us anything about your design yet. Please edit your question and explain the *context* e.g. what is the application? Can you add a schematic (or at least part) showing relevant components? What exactly is the problem with connecting a crystal oscillator? Do you need a standard logic-level clock signal (e.g. 5 V / 3.3 V), or something different? The more detail you add, the better any answers will be. Thanks

Comment: @SamGibson Sorry for that. I edited the question now. Standard logic-level is fine for this application. I have seen in some designs that the 2 pins of the crystal oscillator are connected to the 2 pins of the microcontroller's OSC1 and OSC2. How should I connect the two pins of the oscillator in my application? I went through lot of information on the internet but I think I am missing something very basic.

Comment: I think you need to consider your data source as well as the clock.  Just clocking along at 5MHz won't do you much good if your data bits are changing other rates.  Also, that "NZ385-512" makes nervous.  That implies a lot of stuff connected to the clock.

Comment: What is sending the data and does it have a clock of its own?

Comment: Yes, you are right @JRE The data source is a microcontroller which sends the data in synchronous with the DATA CLOCK, it also has a PIXEL CLOCK and other stuff. For simplicity, I modified the block diagram. Those clock lines and data lines are directly connected to the printer without any problem. But for them all to work, there should a fundamental clock which is a constant 5MHz clock. This fundamental clock should be connected as an external device as the microcontroller board cannot be modified.

Comment: @ocrdu A microcontroller is sending the data with its own DATACLOCK, I am designing an adapter interface between that microcontroller board and the printer's interface connector. This only consists of a power conversion circuit and a fundamental clock generator.

Comment: The clock will probably have to come from the MCU, or at the least you're going to need to be able to use it to drive DMA or very carefully written code to push our the data on time.  You are a long way from making this work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A clock oscillator module requires no more than power connections with a bypass capacitor to produce a square wave output at approximately 50% duty cycle (for example, 45-55% guaranteed). You just need to pick one that is suitable for your desired frequency, supply voltage, output type and accuracy/stability. There may be an enable input that needs to be tied to an appropriate logic level.

If that is insufficiently close to 50% duty cycle, you can procure an oscillator that operates at double your desired frequency (10MHz in this case) and divide the output with a flip-flop, such as 74HC74.

For example, the [ECS-5032MV-100](https://ecsxtal.com/store/pdf/ECS-5032MV.pdf) which is a 10MHz oscillator which operates from 1.6 to 3.6V Vdd, plus a [74ALVC74](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74ALVC74.pdf).